# How can I get the selectionOffset relative to the parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you click on the 'M' the offset should be 6 but because it's inside another element `getSelection()` returns the offset of that particular element, is it possible to return the offset from the parent span instead ?

```js
l.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    console.log(window.getSelection().anchorOffset)
})
```

```css
body{ background: #1a1d21; font-size: 2em;}
span{color: white}
```

```html
<span id='l'>begin<span>Middle</span>end</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned "*because it's inside another element `getSelection().anchorOffset` returns the offset of that particular element*". In other words the offset you're looking for is what you have so far + the length of the text before the target element .

```js
el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const anchorNode = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
  const content = e.currentTarget.textContent.split(e.target.textContent);
  console.log(content[0].length + anchorNode);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #1a1d21;
  font-size: 2em;
}

span {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<span id="el">begin<span>Middle</span>end</span>
```

Comment: This would only work for this small example and not for actual projects, right? It would break as soon as there are multiple occurrences of the letter "M"? Or do I miss something?

Comment: It splits based on the text content of the node that the click event started in, which is a terrible approach to this problem, since if you start in the "end" section, for example, it will split on the first occurance of "end" - and not necessarily the one you started on. This code will not work if the HTML in question is `<span>end<span>end</span>end</span>`, for example. Downvoting since this is not a real solution.